# How do I satisfy an "inexact function" error in Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Ok so I've got a pretty straightforward scenario which works but my issue is keeping flow happy.

```
const StatusImage: React$Element<*> =
            props.statusImage ? (props.statusImage) : ((): React$Element<*> => <div/>);
```

I want to display a `StatusImage` within my React component if the user of the component supplies one through the `statusImage` prop. Otherwise I just want to leave the space where the icon would be blank.

It works but I get the following flow error which I can't solve. I'm using `flow-bin` version 0.113.0

```
Cannot assign props.statusImage ? props.statusImage : (...) => <div /> to StatusImage because inexact function [1] is
incompatible with exact React.Element [2].

 [2] 121|         const StatusImage: React$Element<*> =
 [1] 122|             props.statusImage ? (props.statusImage) : ((): React$Element<*> => <div/>);
```

I've google the **inexact function** flow error but can't find anything anywhere that solves my issue. This appears to be quite a new error which has only started to be checked for recently in flow.

Comment: Is `props.statusImage` something that you would render like `<props.statusImage />` or `{props.statusImage}`?

Comment: I render ```<StatusImage/>``` so indirectly yes ```props.statusImage``` would be rendered if it was set. I don't use it directly after the line of code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some further trial and error this seems to work....

```
 const StatusImage: React$Element<*> | () => React$Element<*> =
            props.statusImage ? (props.statusImage) : ((): React$Element<*> => <div/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [`React.ComponentType<Props>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype) type if `props.statusImage` can contain a stateless functional component or a class component. If `props.statusImage` can only be a stateless functional component then you could use [`React.StatelessFunctionalComponent<Props>`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-statelessfunctionalcomponent).

```
import * as React from "react";

type StatusImageComponent = React.ComponentType<{}>;

type Props = { statusImage?: StatusImageComponent };

function Foo(props: Props) {
  const StatusImage =
    props.statusImage === undefined ? () => <div /> : props.statusImage;
  return (
    <div>
      <StatusImage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAMozIwCuqAkiGQBzLAGESkAHZYp8ALyYqMAHQTwEGXIAqLLAB4A3gF8AfPUZ64ABWJh0iw3FRdeAoaID8ALg6u+giLikpqy8MYWBDxS+MCacABiEBAAFGB2qL62EPYAlHCGdHBwuJouftwBHmzyRcVw6TmoKi6V7kFw8l1w0QAmWATAMr1wnnAp+fKmcPq9wABucAD0076N9i3+7aL0xZS8UFLjdcWzC6Yn9fqcbYGiyxf1M0tz849wufTGdEA)